# Developing Geographic Thematic Maps with R

Tags: r, dictionary, geolocation, geospatial

There are clearly a number of packages in R for all sorts of spatial analysis. That can by seen in the [CRAN Task View: Analysis of Spatial Data](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html). These packages are numerous and diverse, but all I want to do is some simple [thematic maps](http://images.google.com/images?q=thematic+map&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=EYiBSqywF5TYNZW8sJ0L&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4). I have data with county and state FIPS codes and I have ESRI shape files of county and state boundaries and the accompanying FIPS codes which allows joining with the data. The shape files could be easily converted to other formats, if needed.

So what's the most straight forward way to create thematic maps with R?

This map looks like it was created with an ESRI Arc product, but this is the type of thing I would like to do with R:

[alt text http://www.infousagov.com/images/choro.jpg](http://www.infousagov.com/images/choro.jpg) Map [copied from here](http://www.infousagov.com/thematicmap.asp).

Comment: Note that this type of map is called a choropleth, and there are some pretty major problems, namely that smaller geographic areas tend to have more people (e.g. east coast vs. Montana) so the visual appearance is biased towards areas of low population density.

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with the raw ESRI data you may find that it has too many vertices.  A rough attempt at generalisation in R can be found at http://github.com/hadley/data-counties/tree/master

Comment: @hadley, I agree completely with your sentiment of 'problems' with choropleths. That's often an issue with the spatial representation of data.

Comment: @JDLong @hadley It might not be such a big deal if you are studying corn rather than people.

Comment: @leoniedu you are correct wrt corn. What I have to deal with is stuff like: The historical volatility of production in big geo regions is lower than the volatility of production in small geo regions simply because of sample size. So it makes it tough to determine true producer level 'riskiness' when the geo regions are of dissimiliar size. But that keeps it fun. :)

Comment: Note: the map link is now broken

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following code has served me well. Customize it a little and you are done.
[image]
<sub>(source: [eduardoleoni.com](http://files.eduardoleoni.com/map.png))</sub>

```
library(maptools)
substitute your shapefiles here
state.map <- readShapeSpatial("BRASIL.shp")
counties.map <- readShapeSpatial("55mu2500gsd.shp")
## this is the variable we will be plotting
counties.map@data$noise <- rnorm(nrow(counties.map@data))
```

heatmap function

```
plot.heat <- function(counties.map,state.map,z,title=NULL,breaks=NULL,reverse=FALSE,cex.legend=1,bw=.2,col.vec=NULL,plot.legend=TRUE) {
  ##Break down the value variable
  if (is.null(breaks)) {
    breaks=
      seq(
          floor(min(counties.map@data[,z],na.rm=TRUE)*10)/10
          ,
          ceiling(max(counties.map@data[,z],na.rm=TRUE)*10)/10
          ,.1)
  }
  counties.map@data$zCat <- cut(counties.map@data[,z],breaks,include.lowest=TRUE)
  cutpoints <- levels(counties.map@data$zCat)
  if (is.null(col.vec)) col.vec <- heat.colors(length(levels(counties.map@data$zCat)))
  if (reverse) {
    cutpointsColors <- rev(col.vec)
  } else {
    cutpointsColors <- col.vec
  }
  levels(counties.map@data$zCat) <- cutpointsColors
  plot(counties.map,border=gray(.8), lwd=bw,axes = FALSE, las = 1,col=as.character(counties.map@data$zCat))
  if (!is.null(state.map)) {
    plot(state.map,add=TRUE,lwd=1)
  }
  ##with(counties.map.c,text(x,y,name,cex=0.75))
  if (plot.legend) legend("bottomleft", cutpoints, fill = cutpointsColors,bty="n",title=title,cex=cex.legend)
  ##title("Cartogram")
}
```

plot it

```
plot.heat(counties.map,state.map,z="noise",breaks=c(-Inf,-2,-1,0,1,2,Inf))
```

Comment: oh that looks really great! I was hoping someone had a code example like this. Thanks!

Comment: Where can you get the .shp files? I need one for the Netherlands, but can't find it

Comment: Hello, is it possible to add an external variable instead of generating a randomized one? To be to the point, I want to plot percent change in projected yields as my variable. Thus, do I need to amend my shape file that contains the map coordinates to have it include the yield data?

Answer (score 17):

Thought I would add some new information here since there has been some activity around this topic since the posting. Here are two great links to "Choropleth Map R Challenge" on the Revolutions blog:

[Choropleth Map R Challenge](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-map-r-challenge.html)

[Choropleth Challenge Results](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html)

Hopefully these are useful for people viewing this question.

All the best,

Jay

Comment: Thanks JD. There is a ton of map plotting information linked through the Revolutions blog now.

Comment: Where can you get the .shp files? I need one for the Netherlands, but can't find it..

Answer (score 11):

Check out the packages

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
```

which are nice for geodata, and

```
library(RColorBrewer)
```

is useful for colouring. [This map](http://picasaweb.google.no/lh/photo/FtqMZz1wTsrcRE9gFX3U-g?feat=directlink) is made with the above packages and this code:

```
VegMap <- readOGR(".", "VegMapFile")
Veg9<-brewer.pal(9,'Set2')
spplot(VegMap, "Veg", col.regions=Veg9,
 +at=c(0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5),
 +main='Vegetation map')
```

`"VegMapFile"` is a shapefile and `"Veg"` is the variable displayed. Can probably be done better with a little work. I don`t seem to be allowed to upload image, here is an link to the image:

Comment: very good info! thank you. When you get a little more reputation you should be able to embed the image.

Comment: Broken link - if you could update it, then perhaps someone with sufficient rep could embed.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the PBSmapping package (see borh the vignette/manual and the demo) and
[this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804770/) O'Reilly *Data  Mashups in R* article (unfortunately it is not free of charge but it worth 4.99$ to download, according [Revolutions blog](http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2009/06/data-mashups-in-r.html) ).

Comment: Its $5 and no DRM which made me more than happy to download on principle alone.  Well written with good code, highly recommend!

Answer (score 4):

It is just three lines!

```
library(maps);
colors = floor(runif(63)*657);
map("state", col = colors, fill = T, resolution = 0)
```

Done!! 
Just change the second line to any vector of 63 elements (each element between 0 and 657, which are members of colors())

Now if you want to get fancy you can write:

```
library(maps);
library(mapproj);
colors = floor(runif(63)*657);
map("state", col = colors, fill = T, projection = "polyconic", resolution = 0);
```

The 63 elements represent the 63 regions whose names you can get by running:

```
map("state")$names;
```

Answer (score 3):

The R Graphics Gallery has a very [similar map](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=113) which should make for a good starting point. The code is here: www.ai.rug.nl/~hedderik/R/US2004 . You'd need to add a legend with the legend() function.

Comment: Nice.  I keep forgetting that the Graphics Gallery is a really neat resource for these kinds of samples.

Comment: Note that the first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble upon this question in the 2020ies, use the magnificent `tmap` package. It's very simple and straightforward and revolutionized making maps in R. Do not bother to investigate this complicated code.
Check the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html).