# Plotting color map with zip codes in R or Python

Tags: python, r, graphics, zipcode

I have some US demographic and firmographic data.
I would like to plot zipcode areas in a state or a smaller region (e.g. city). Each area would be annotated by color and/or text specific to that area. The output would be similar to http://maps.huge.info/ but a) with annotated text; b) pdf output; c) scriptable in R or Python.

Is there any package and code that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I am assuming you want static maps.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eduardoleoni.com](http://files.eduardoleoni.com/mapUS.png))</sub>

1) Get the shapefiles of the [zip](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/zt_metadata.html) boundaries and [state](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/st2000.html) boundaries at census.gov:

2) Use the plot.heat function I posted in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260965/developing-geographic-thematic-maps-with-r).

For example (assumes you have the maryland shapefiles in the map subdirectory):

```
library(maptools)
##substitute your shapefiles here
state.map <- readShapeSpatial("maps/st24_d00.shp")
zip.map <- readShapeSpatial("maps/zt24_d00.shp")
## this is the variable we will be plotting
zip.map@data$noise <- rnorm(nrow(zip.map@data))
## put the lab point x y locations of the zip codes in the data frame for easy retrieval
labelpos <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(zip.map@polygons, function(x) x@labpt)))
names(labelpos) <- c("x","y")                        
zip.map@data <- data.frame(zip.map@data, labelpos)
## plot it
png(file="map.png")
## plot colors
plot.heat(zip.map,state.map,z="noise",breaks=c(-Inf,-2,-1,0,1,2,Inf))
## plot text
with(zip.map@data[sample(1:nrow(zip.map@data), 10),] , text(x,y,NAME))
dev.off()
```

Comment: The links to to shape files at www.census.gov are broken... it took me a while to find them.  Try this URL: http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main.  Then use the dropdown to select "Zip Code Tabulation Areas" and "States (and equivalent)."

Comment: Do you mind explaining how I can map values from a csv file that has a zip code column and some other data columns to use this (apologies if the answer is obvious, but I don't really know R at all)? Specifically, I am having trouble figuring out what I should put for `zip.map@data$noise <- rnorm(nrow(zip.map@data))` `labelpos <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(zip.map@polygons, function(x) x@labpt)))` and `zip.map@data <- data.frame(zip.map@data, labelpos)`

Comment: If that site is down for maintenance, you can use this link: https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to do this in R (see the [spatial view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html)); many of these [depend on the "maps" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html).

- Check out this [cool example of the US 2004 election](http://www.ai.rug.nl/~hedderik/R/US2004/).  It ends up looking like this:[image]
- Here's a slightly ugly example of a model [that uses the "maps" package with "lattice".](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/sources/source_146.R)
- Andrew Gelman made some very nice plots like this.  See, for instance, [this blog post on red states/blue states](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/03/how_went_the_20.html) and [this follow up post](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/05/discussion_and.html).
- Here's a very simple example [using the "gmaps" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmaps/index.html), which shows a map of Arrests by state for arrests per 100,000 for Murder:

  ```
  require(gmaps)
  data(USArrests)
  attach(USArrests)
  grid.newpage()
  grid.frame(name="map")
  grid.pack("map",USALevelPlot(states=rownames(USArrests),levels=Murder,col.fun=reds),height=unit(1,'null'))
  grid.pack("map",gradientLegendGrob(at=quantile(Murder),col.fun=reds),side="bottom",height=unit(.2,'npc'))
  detach(USArrests)
  ```

Comment: It seems like these examples are at the county, not zipcode, level

Answer (score 3):

Someone may have something more direct for you, but I found O'Reilly's 'Data Mashups in R' very interesting... in part, it's a spatial mapping of home foreclosure auctions.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804770/

Comment: Plus, no DRM and only $5...hard to beat that deal!

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can use shapefiles from the US census along with the `basemap` package.  Here is an example of [filling in states](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/examples/fillstates.py) according to population.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rich and sophisticated series of packages in R to plot, do analysis, and other functions related to GIS.  One place to get started is the CRAN task view on [Spatial Data](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html):
This is a complex and sometimes arcane world, and takes some work to understand.

If you are looking for a free, very functional mapping application, may I suggest:

MapWindow ( mapwindow.com)

Comment: I could not find anything in that CRAN view that would help me visualize zip code statistics on a map. The closest I got was the package muRL.

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel Levine at TechCrunch Trends](http://trends.techcrunch.com/) has done nice things with the `maps` package in R.  He has code available on his site, too.

Paul's suggestion of looking into Processing - which Ben Fry used to make zipdecode - is also a good one, if you're up for learning a (Java-like) new language.

Comment: thanks Matt, yes the trends maps are zip code level, but instead of shading zipcode areas, I actually mapped the zipcodes to lat/long coords. Anyone is welcome to the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, a long way around might be to use something like this:

http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2006/07/new-google-maps-us-zip-code-mashups.html

To map your data. If that wasn't quite what you wanted, you can get raw zip code shapefiles from census.gov and do it manually, which is quite a pain.

Also, if you haven't seen it, this is a neat way to interact with similar data, and might offer some pointers:

http://benfry.com/zipdecode/

Comment: nice too, but these are visualizations of zip codes locations/boundaries. I am looking for a flexible way in R or Python to generate maps with custom-colored or text-annotated zip regions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this excellent online visualization tool by IBM
http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/manyeyes/

**EDIT** FYI, ManyEyes uses the [Prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/gallery/) for some of its viz. Even though it is a java-based framework, they also provide a Flash/ActionScript tool for the web.

Comment: Isnt that the same thing that was presented by Hans Rosling on TED a few years ago

Comment: nice, but manyeyes doesn't answer my question. I think it's very different from gapminder. Wattenberg is a visualization guy, Rosling is a social scientist, and the different approach shows.