# Help plotting Geographic Data in R using PBSMapping and Shapefiles

Tags: r, mapping, gis, geospatial, esri

Using [O'Reilly's Data Mashups in R](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804770/) as inspiration, I'm trying to plot a handful of addresses on a shapefile of Salt Lake County, Utah found [here](http://gis.utah.gov/sgid-vector-download/utah-sgid-vector-gis-data-layer-download-index?fc=CensusTracts2000).

I have data frame geoTable:

```
> geoTable
         address        Y         X EID
1    130 E 300 S 40.76271 -111.8872   1
2    875 E 900 S 40.74992 -111.8660   2
3   2200 S 700 E 40.72298 -111.8714   3
4    702 E 100 S 40.76705 -111.8707   4
5 177 East 200 S 40.76518 -111.8859   5
6    702 3rd ave 40.77264 -111.8683   6
7   2175 S 900 E 40.72372 -111.8652   7
8   803 E 2100 S 40.72556 -111.8680   8
```

And I've coerced it into an eventData object:

```
> addressEvents<-as.EventData(geoTable,projection=NA)
> addressEvents
         address        Y         X EID
1    130 E 300 S 40.76271 -111.8872   1
2    875 E 900 S 40.74992 -111.8660   2
3   2200 S 700 E 40.72298 -111.8714   3
4    702 E 100 S 40.76705 -111.8707   4
5 177 East 200 S 40.76518 -111.8859   5
6    702 3rd ave 40.77264 -111.8683   6
7   2175 S 900 E 40.72372 -111.8652   7
8   803 E 2100 S 40.72556 -111.8680   8
```

So it looks like I've got everything I need to plot-but its not working.  When I load the shapefile and plot using

```
addPoints(addressEvents,col="red",cex=.5)
```

I'm left looking at an empty shapefile.  Additionally, when I try and run findPolys against my eventData object, it returns NULL.

```
> findPolys(addressEvents,myShapeFile)
NULL
```

How can I make this work?  I was able to complete the O'Reilly tutorial without any problems and am having difficulty figuring out where I'm going wrong here.  I dont know if its the shapefile, my data frame, or whateverelse.

Here are the commands I use to import my data and shapefile

```
slc<-read.table('~/utah.txt',sep=',',header=TRUE,strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

myShapeFile<-importShapefile("/Users/neil/Downloads/SGID93_DEMOGRAPHIC_CensusTracts2000/SGID93_DEMOGRAPHIC_CensusTracts2000",readDBF=TRUE)
```

Comment: My gut tells me that its not my data, rather its my shapefile.  I'm really new to the concept of shapefiles.  When I plotPolys using O'Reilly's example shapefile, the X and Y axes look like long and lat.  When I plotPolys using the Utah shapefiles, the X and Y axes look like a different numbering system.

Comment: I had never used the PBSmapping package. I have messed slightly with maptools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also want to look at these related questions, especially at Eduardo's responses:

- [plotting-color-map-with-zip-codes-in-r-or-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441717/plotting-color-map-with-zip-codes-in-r-or-python/)
- [developing-geographic-thematic-maps-with-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260965/developing-geographic-thematic-maps-with-r)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like PBSmapping uses some crude heuristics to work out the projection from the .prj file.  (see help(importShapefile)). I personally don't understand all the stuff inside a prj file but using this website www.spatialreference.org I reckon your map matches

http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26912/

Whenever I get a new shape file I find it's projection system on this website and then look for the proj4 string, which in this case is 
"+proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

(Like I said I don't know PBSmapping, but you can read this in using maptools as follows)

```
library(maptools)
sf=readShapeSpatial("SGID93_DEMOGRAPHIC_CensusTracts2000.shp",proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

and then convert to latlong using

```
library(rgdal)

sftransformed=spTransform(sf,CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

and

plot(sftransformed,axes=T)

gives a plot with the right units on the axes.

Not sure if PBSmapping understands a proj4 string? Looks like it doesn't to be honest.