# Combining bordering shapefiles in R

Tags: r, gis, esri, shapefile

I have five shapefiles of bordering counties in California that I am trying to combine into one large shapefile and maintain the original borders of the counties.  I then want to plot points such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481032/help-plotting-geographic-data-in-r-using-pbsmapping-and-shapefiles) so the map only needs to be a simple map of county boundaries.  Is there a way to do this in R or will I have to use something like ArcGIS?

There is extensive documentation about merging within a shapefile such as [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=267802) where both shapefiles have the same coordinates.  But no documentation on shapefiles that only partially share coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to put all the borders into one data set then you can do that with `sp`/`rgdal` easily enough, but if you need to actually merge borders geometrically (clip/join/dissolve) and so on the support in R is not that simple.

Roughly the simple option is read each shapefile with `readOGR`, then `spRbind` them together. If `rgdal` presents difficulties for building/installing then there are other options for reading shapefiles in various packages.

btw, "something like ArcGIS" but much closer to "free": www.manifold.net

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a Free and Open Source solution I highly recommend QGIS or uDIG or OpenJump or MapWindows. You can do all the shapefile manipulation you want in these packages, they are all GIS software.

I am sorry I do not of a way to do this in R and I am not sure I would trust the result - better to use a hammer for a nail than to use a screwdriver.

If you want to programmaticly want to alter the shapefiles let me know and I will recommend some python and java libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will check those out.  And python is choice #2 for trying to do this, any libraries you suggest would be appreciated.  Obviously searching 'python map' is not going to be very helpful...

Comment: I would recommend shapely or the python bindings for geos