# Error when combining shapefiles

Tags: r, merge, gis, projection, shapefile

I am trying to merge two polygon shapefiles (spatialpolygondataframe, projected).

I have tried the solution in 
[Append/Combine Shape Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961898/append-combine-shape-files/29103886#29103886)
however, I cannot seem to make it work.

The `rbind` only works on SpatialPolygons, so I get rid of my attribute table. Still i get the following error:

```
rbind(t.poly1, t.poly2, fix.duplicated.IDs=TRUE)

Fehler in function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"logical"’
```

I dont really have power over the format of the proj4string:

```
CRS arguments: +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

Do you have any explanation or solution as to what I could do to enable the merge?

Comment: Are you sure both objects are (proper) `SpatialPolygons`?

Comment: The stronger form of @RomanLuštrik comment is "Can you create a reproducible example?"

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to plot two (or more) shapefiles together on one plot, you do not need to combine the two shapefiles; they can simply be added as layers on to one plot.

Using shapefiles of the UK and Ireland as examples, we obtain them from DIVA-GIS and unzip them in to shapes/:

```
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/GBR_adm.zip",
          destfile = "shapes/GBR_adm.zip")
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/IRL_adm.zip",
          destfile = "shapes/IRL_adm.zip")
unzip("shapes/GBR_adm.zip", exdir = "shapes/")
unzip("shapes/IRL_adm.zip", exdir = "shapes/")
```

Then, load the required packages:

```
packages <- c("maptools", "rgeos", "rgdal")
sapply(packages, install.packages, dependencies = T)
sapply(packages, require, character.only = T)
rm(packages)
```

Then load the shapefiles in to memory:

```
gb <- readOGR("shapes/", "GBR_adm0")
eire <- readOGR("shapes/", "IRL_adm0")
```

These can then be plot:

```
plot(gb)
plot(eire, add = T)
```

Which gives you the result of both shapefiles:

[image]

If you do want to merge/combine both shapefiles in R, I would use the `spRbind()` function in the `rgdal` package:

```
n <- length(slot(gb, "polygons"))
gbEire <- spChFIDs(eire, as.character(n))  # so shapefiles have unique IDs
gbEire <- spRbind(gbEire, gb)
writeOGR(gbEire, dsn = "shapes/", layer = "gbEire", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Which should write a new shapefile with both original shapefiles merged in the `shapes/` directory.

Comment: Hey Phil, thank you very much for your response. I do infact want to merge the shapefiles and not just plot them together. I now went into the source code of the package "taRifx.geo" and tried the function rbind.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame() and that worked with out any problems, or so it seems...

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you. What about writing it up as an answer to your own question so others know it is an option if they read this post?

Comment: Hey Phil, yes, like I said, I just used the rbind.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame() function that I found in the package and with that it works fine! So I guess the problem was the underneath mentioned fact that it an rbind() from a different packages was used!

Answer (score 1):

```
rbind(t.poly1, t.poly2, fix.duplicated.IDs=TRUE)

Fehler in function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"logical"’
```

Its actually trying to get a proj4string of the `fix.duplicated.IDs` argument. Because your objects are SpatialPolygons, the `rbind` from the `sp` package is being used rather than the package mentioned in the linked post.

Have you tried:

```
s1=SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0)))),ID=1)))
s2=SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0)))),ID=1)))
proj4string(s1)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(s2)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
rbind(s1,s2) # errors...
```

So just use this handy arg:

```
rbind(s1,s2,makeUniqueIDs=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you Spacedman, that also works fine as well and is much more convienient than the source code!