# Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have thousand files and each one contains a `.shp`. The names of my files are  `file_sh1,file_sh2,..,file_sh5000` and the names of the `.shps` are the same.I am trying to read them in R and then export them (all `.shps` in one file) but I get the error `"Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file"`.

my code so far:

```
fle=list()
for (i in 1:5000){
  fle[[i]]=readShapeSpatial("fle/file_sh",i,"/file_sh",i,".shp")
}
```

How can I read the `.shps` from the files and export them in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to paste your string:

```
fle=list()
for (i in 1:5000){
  fle[[i]]=readShapeSpatial(paste0("fle/file_sh",i,"/file_sh",i,".shp"))
}
```

Example of paste0:

```
> i=1
> paste0("fle/file_sh",i,"/file_sh",i,".shp")
[1] "fle/file_sh1/file_sh1.shp"
```

For the second part of your question, see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155328/merging-multiple-spatialpolygondataframes-into-1-spdf-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961898/append-combine-shape-files) or [here](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/merging-several-shapefiles-into-one-td6401613.html).

Comment: Thank you @Florian. That was a stupid mistake. As for the second part of my question, I did not want to merge my .shps but to save them in one folder instead of 5000. Thanks a lot!