# combining multiple shapefiles in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I have a folder with about 100 point shapefiles that are locations obtained while scat sampling of an ungulate species. I would like to merge all these point shapefiles into one shapefile in R. All the point data were in .gpx format initially which I then changed to shapefiles.

I am fairly new to R,so I am very confused as on how to do it and could not find codes that merged or combined more than a few shapefiles. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264250/merge-two-shapefiles-in-r?rq=1. And note that [gis.se] might be a better place to ask future questions about shapefiles.

Comment: Also possible duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961898/append-combine-shape-files

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a bit more info (i.e. when you read them what spatial type are they?; are you using sp/rgdal or sf? when you say "merge" what exactly do you mean output-wise/what if there are duplicates?). Also, this might be better served on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13):

Building on @M_Merciless .. 
for long lists you can use

```
all_schools <- do.call(rbind, shapefile_list)
```

Or, alternatively, the very fast:

```
all_schools <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(x))
```

Comment: bind_rows from dplyr package will also work on lists, dplyr::bind_rows(shapefile_list)

Answer (score 11):

```
library(sf)
```

list all the shapefiles within the folder location

```
file_list <- list.files("shapefile/folder/location", pattern = "*shp", full.names = TRUE)
```

read all shapefiles, store as a list

```
shapefile_list <- lapply(file_list, read_sf)
```

append the separate shapefiles, in my example there are 4 shapefiles, this can probably be improved by using a for loop or apply function for a longer list.

```
all_schools <- rbind(shapefile_list[[1]], shapefile_list[[2]], shapefile_list[[3]], shapefile_list[[4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a solution that I think is "tidier"

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

# Getting all file paths
shapefiles <- 'my/data/folder' |>
  dir_ls(recurse = TRUE, regexp = 'shp$') 

# Loading all files
sfdf <- shapefiles |>
  map(st_read) |>
  bind_rows()
```

Admittedly, more lines of code but personally I think the code is much easier to read and comprehend this way.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @JanLauGe's elegant answer, just a caveat to consider: if your shapefiles do not share a common CRS just binding the rows can be problematic. Just as a precaution you might want to pick a `fixed_crs` of your choice and then reproject all your shapefiles to such:

```
fixed_crs <- st_crs(read_sf("SHAPEFILE OF YOUR CHOICE"))
```

and then proceed with the third chunk of code of the answer above reprojecting each shapefile to your `fixed_crs` as follows:

```
# Loading all files
sfdf <- shapefiles |>
map(st_read) |>
map(st_transform, crs = fixed_crs) |>  
## Note the line above reprojects each shapefile to fixed_crs
bind_rows()
```