# making a choropleth in R: merging zip code shapefiles from multiple states

Tags: r, shapefile

Motivated by the post here, [Developing Geographic Thematic Maps with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260965/developing-geographic-thematic-maps-with-r), I was thinking about constructing a choropleth map based on zip codes.  I've downloaded the shape files for New Hampshire and Maine from http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html, but I'm interested in combining or merging the .shp files from these two states.

Is there a mechanism in the `maptools` package for doing this kind of merge or concatenation of two .shp files after you read them in using `readShapeSpatial()`?  Also welcome input if e.g. using the `RgoogleMaps` package would be easier.

Comment: This this link (http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/suggestion-to-MERGE-or-UNION-3-shapefiles-td5914413.html#a5916751) on merging. The nabble archive should be a gold mine for handling spatial data.

Comment: Mmm... didn't know R-sig-geo had made it onto Nabble. Unfortunate that it isn't grouped in with the other R forums.

Comment: It took me almost five years of GIS to realize this but... it's "choropleth" not "chloropleth"

Comment: @J. Winchester, good point...I just corrected the title to "choropleth."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed up on the link posted by Roman Luštrik, and the following answer is a slight modification of http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/suggestion-to-MERGE-or-UNION-3-shapefiles-td5914413.html#a5916751.

The following code will allow you to merge the `.shp` files obtained from [Census 2000 5-Digit ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs) Cartographic Boundary Files](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html) and plot them.

In this case, I downloaded the `.shp` files and associated `.dbf` and `.shx` files for Massachusetts, New Hampshire, and Maine.

```
library('maptools')
library('rgdal')

setwd('c:/location.of.shp.files')

# this location has the shapefiles for zt23_d00 (Maine), zt25_d00 (Mass.), and zt33_d00 (New Hampshire).

# columns.to.keep
# allows the subsequent spRbind to work properly

columns.to.keep <- c('AREA', 'PERIMETER', 'ZCTA', 'NAME', 'LSAD', 'LSAD_TRANS')

files <- list.files(pattern="*.shp$", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE) 

uid <-1 

# get polygons from first file

poly.data<- readOGR(files[1], gsub("^.*/(.*).shp$", "\\1", files[1])) 
n <- length(slot(poly.data, "polygons"))
poly.data <- spChFIDs(poly.data, as.character(uid:(uid+n-1))) 
uid <- uid + n 
poly.data <- poly.data[columns.to.keep]

# combine remaining polygons with first polygon

for (i in 2:length(files)) {
    temp.data <- readOGR(files[i], gsub("^.*/(.*).shp$", "\\1",files[i]))
    n <- length(slot(temp.data, "polygons")) 
    temp.data <- spChFIDs(temp.data, as.character(uid:(uid+n-1))) 
    temp.data <- temp.data[columns.to.keep]
    uid <- uid + n 
    poly.data <- spRbind(poly.data,temp.data) 
}

plot(poly.data)

# save new shapefile

combined.shp <- 'combined.shp'
writeOGR(poly.data, dsn=combined.shp, layer='combined1', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Answer (score 0):

[GeoMerge](http://www.vdstech.com/geomerge.htm) is a free tool for merging Shapefiles. Merges SHP and DBF parts. Seems to work OK, but I haven't pushed it too much.

Comment: the link is broken. but there is a package `geomerge` on CRAN